# ReactJS and Material-UI not rendering the data from nested map

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am trying to create Tabs and populate each of them with the data from a json file using Reactjs and material-ui(older version).I have tried to follow couple of StackOverflow question and fix the nested map inside the jsx(either return or use () instead of curly braces). But it is still not rendering the data under each tab. I have got the sample code here in [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-tab-show-data-from-api-call-forked-g4phqd). Can someone please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When mapping the tab panels you were passing the value of the object not the state of the current panel. This is what your code block should look like. Just replace "value" with "currentTab".

```
{Object.entries(groupedReleasesData).map(([key, value], index) => (
    <TabPanel value={currentTab} index={index}> //<--
      <Grid container spacing={1} justify="center">
        {Object.entries(value).map(([k, v]) => (
          <Card key={v.name + "-card"}>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h6" component="span">
                {v.name}
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </TabPanel>
  ))}
```